# Convert Varchar Duration time to time

Tags: sql-server

I need my code to add the varchar `CPUTM` field + varchar `CPUZIPTIM` field which both has time values to see if greater than 2 hours. How do I do this when both fields are varchar. The value in `CPUTM` field is  `'335:55:20.97'` duration time.  My code is below.

```
      CPUTM =     335:55:20.97 duration time
     CPUZIPTM =     0:00:01.96  duration time


select * FROM [SMF_DATA].[dbo].[System_Management_Facility]
WHERE ((convert(varchar(13), CONVERT(time, CPUTM) + CONVERT(time, CPUZIPTM))) 
       > '02:00:00.00')
```

Using SQL server 2012 Enterprise Edition.

Comment: If these values are 24 hours or more, they cannot be converted to `time` (in SQL-Server).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the format in the 2 columns is `hours:mm:ss[.fff]` where `hours` can be even more than 24, I think this would work:

```
SELECT smf.* 
FROM [SMF_DATA].[dbo].[System_Management_Facility] AS smf
  CROSS APPLY
    ( SELECT CHARINDEX(':', CPUTM)    AS i1, 
             CHARINDEX(':', CPUZIPTM) AS i2,
             LEN(CPUTM)    AS len1,
             LEN(CPUZIPTM) AS len2
    ) AS a
  CROSS APPLY
    ( SELECT CONVERT(int, LEFT(CPUTM, i1-1))
             + CONVERT(int, LEFT(CPUZIPTM, i2-1)) AS number_of_hours,
             CONVERT(datetime, '00:' + RIGHT(CPUTM,    len1-i1)) AS d1,  -- implicit 
             CONVERT(datetime, '00:' + RIGHT(CPUZIPTM, len2-i2)) AS d2   -- dates
                              -- both d1 and d2 get implicit date of '1900-01-01'
    ) AS b
WHERE 
    number_of_hours + DATEDIFF(hour, '19000101', d1 + d2) >= 2 ;
```

The `CROSS APPLY` are not really needed, they are there so the logic is split in parts and so you don't have a huge complicated final condition.

---

If you wanted a different check (say 10 minutes instead of 2 hours), it would need only this change:

```
WHERE 
    number_of_hours = 0
  AND
    DATEDIFF(minute, '19000101', d1 + d2) >= 10 ;
```

Comment: Excellent answer ypercube. I am getting an error on the LEFTIndex built-in function. How do I get to work.

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 4
'LEFTINDEX' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT'.

Comment: I am using SQL server 2012 Enterprise Edition

Comment: No problem. You are a big help. I will try with charindex.

Comment: Now I am getting error  Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT'.

Comment: I re copied your code above and it works. Wow!! thanks for all your help. Where do I give you credit for solving this problem.

Comment: Yes. I learning how to use this forum.

Comment: Hello ypercube. I like the last code for hours. Can you change to minutes where the same code is greater than 10 minutes.

Comment: It would be better for you, if you experimented. Remove the `WHERE` clause and add the various results in the `SELECT` list, e.g.: `SELECT smf.*, a.*, b.*, d1+d2 AS d1d2 ...` and see what it shows and experiment with `DATEDIFF`.

Comment: If figured it out. Thanks for all your help ypercube.

Comment: You can remove the old comments. (and if this answer helped you, you can "accept" it by clicking on the mark on the left.) You don't have to do that, you can wait for other answers if you like.